# Create Installer for MVC -4 Web application

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, setup-project

Here is my problem. I have a web application I wanna deliver this application to Customer so I need to create exe for this web application. When user clicks exe, it shows all the application setting to be changed with in a windows form. When user fills those values and clicks finish button. After clicking finish button changes appsettings  should be applied to the web.config file and web application should be copy to the given folder.

Comment: If you want to deliver it to a customer, why dont u publish it, and give all the files generated in the target folder in publishing wizard.

Comment: There are lots of configuration have to be changed. eg Report service URL,Datasets folder... I don't know those values. Most of the time, when client deploy web application, they miss some of these fields. So I wanna just create an EXE to do that.